# Is it possible for a HIVE table to point to a dynamic Location based on a variable like CURRENT_DATE?

Tags: hive, hiveddl

I want to be able to define (or create) a HIVE table with location having a variable. As the variable value changes, query on the HIVE table should read the files under the new location based on the variable value. Specifically, I want to use CURRENT_DATE to let the HIVE table fetch from a different folder each day.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Location is a part of table/partition DDL. You can use

```
ALTER TABLE/PARTITION SET LOCATION
```

or add partition with new location:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION
```

and pass partition specification to the query as a parameter